# netbeans 7.4 inline js code formatting and auto completion

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, netbeans-7, bugzilla

When any JS is embedded within HTML or PHP pages, Netbeans doesn't highlight the syntax and doesn't provide auto completion.

The sample code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Steps Template</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/initializer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/database.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bg">
        <div id="mediaMini" style="">
            <div id="bgBlock" style="opacity:0;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var options = {
                'imgPath': 'images',
                'audioPath': 'audio'
            };
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function preloadAllImages() {
                    var imagesLoaded = 0;
                    var images2PreLoad = new Array();
                    for (var i in universalStepsData) {
                        images2PreLoad.push(options.imgPath + '/' + (universalStepsData[i].imageSrc));
                    }
                    var loading = function loadAllImages(callback) {
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = images2PreLoad[imagesLoaded];
                        $(img).load(function() {
                            imagesLoaded++;
                            if (imagesLoaded == images2PreLoad.length) {
                                initialise('bgBlock', options);
                            }
                            else
                                loadAllImages(callback);
                        });
                    };
                    loading();
                }
                preloadAllImages();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

My netbeans about page shows the following information.

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528) 
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 7.4 Patch 2 
Java: 1.7.0_51; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03 
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_51-b13 
System: Windows 8 version 6.2 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_AU (nb) 
User directory: C:\Users\Nisarg\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4 
Cache directory: C:\Users\Nisarg\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4

As some users suggested I have also checked in **Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files** and checked that fle extension **JS** has **text/javascript** associated with it.

I also made sure that netbeans is up to date and all the plugins are up to date as well.

How to solve this issue? How can I get formatting and auto completion back?

Answer (score 1):

**Sharing this for those who might be having the same problem.** This doesn't provide solution but observations. (This was too big for a comment)

Well turns out no one could come up with a definite solution. I even opened a [ticket in Bugzilla](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242250) but no response from there either.

Well I was sharing the project with other guys and they were using netbeans 7.3 while I upgraded to 7.4. I believe this was a the problem where the conflict was occurring. Once I reverted back to 7.3 all was good.

Once version 8 was released, I upgraded to 8 while the other fellas were still at 7.3. Till now (touch wood) it hasn't caused any issues.

So in a nutshell, it seems like 7.4 and 7.3 might have internal conflict. Or might not but they both don't work together on same project at same time.